# ARM assembly DCD bad instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

I am using yagarto's arm-none-eabi to compile the assembly code, but it gives the message

```
Error: bad instruction `a DCD 1,2,3'
```

When I am using the DCD instruction

Is it not legal to use? If not, how could I reserve memory spaces for data in ARM?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DCD` directive is for RealView's assembler. If you're using the GNU assembler, try this instead:

```
a: .word 1,2,3
```

Note that you might have to take care of alignment yourself (`DCD` automatically aligns the data on a word-boundary - I'm not sure that `.word` does that).

Comment: for double word, is it a: .dword 1,2,3 ?

Comment: For a 64-bit doubleword you can use `.quad`

Comment: `.word` doesn't have any magic; if you want alignment to 2^2 = 4 bytes, use `.p2align 2` before `.word` to insert 0 to 3 bytes of padding.

Answer (score -4):

You try this way
a DCD 123
In here DCD take only Integer 32 bit wise

Comment: I think `dcd` does take a list of values, in assemblers that support it.  Most assemblers have data pseudo-instructions that work this way.